# Video background on scroll playing not smooth

Tags: javascript, scroll, html5-video

I implement a video background that plays by scroll, based on this pen:
[Original](https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/DPbRMz)

I changed only the video URL, and with my video, the transition on the scroll is not smooth:
[My video](https://codepen.io/orenroth/pen/eYVGydq)

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="https://staging-datagen.kinsta.cloud/app/uploads/2022/05/DG_Full_Scroll_noScreen-1-1.mp4"></source>
```

I tried many things (changing the format, resizing the resolution, and lowering the quality of the video) none of them worked.

Do you have any idea why it is happening?

Comment: The original video used has a much higher frame rate, and lower picture quality (2000 frames, compared to your 600). WebM is also more performant than MP4, but I think the main issue is that the length of your video is short / less frames, so there is going to be bigger jump between each scene.

Comment: In the original, you can change the webp with mp4 version which works as well. As I said, I did lower my video quality, but nothing worked.

Comment: _"Why it is happening?"_ most likely the decoder can't keep up (keyframes issue). Try adding keyframes every 1 second. The best solution is to either use a series of Jpegs or else create bitmaps (imageData) from the video frames by code on page load (meaning draw them, keep these drawn imageDatas in an Array). Cycling through the Array to show images will be smooth/fast. See this example: https://jordicenzano.github.io/frame-accurate-scrubbing/ui/player/example_player.html?m=../../media/transcoded/scrubbingTestV3/854x480/main_manifest.json

Answer (score 0):

Using ffprobe I saw that in the entire 10 sec clip (300 frames) of our animation there are only 2 keyframes. This is strange since usually keyframes will be set every 90 frames or so by default. In the Google Chrome logo clip for example, there are 41 keyframes in the 31 second clip.

Converting our video with reduced key frame distance to every 5 frames - solved the problem!

https://staging-datagen.kinsta.cloud/app/uploads/2022/05/DG_Full_Scroll_noScreen-1-1_kfd5.mp4